# Spring Security AJAX / JSON Login Issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security with the login form being submitted via Ajax. I have created my own custom authenticationFailureHandler and my own custom authenticationSuccessHandler. I'm not sure if my issue lies in my Spring / Java code or on my client side code. I've also seen the cross site scripting protection could be causing the issue. When I login it does authenticate fine, but i actually get a new HTML page with my JSON on it but the content type is html/text.

[image]

When the login is unsuccessful I get the same thing.

[image]

The Request and Response Headers do not look right to me. First there are no response headers, and secondly the request headers does not have X-Requested-With.

Some items to note

1. I am using Spring Boot 1.2.5
2. I have CSRF enabled in Spring Security, it is a requirement from client
3. There cannot be a login page, the login must be in the top right of the top navigation / header, hence why I am submitted the from via JS/Ajax

This is what the login form will look like:

[image]

Here are my custom handlers

```
@Component
public class AuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        userMapper.incrementFailedLogin(request.getParameter("sec-user"));

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().print("{\"success\": false}");
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

-

```
@Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

        userMapper.updateUserOnAuthSuccess(request.getParameter("sec-user"));

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().print("{\"success\": true}");
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

My Spring Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/about","/public/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("sec-user")
                    .passwordParameter("sec-password")
                    .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                    .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("remember-me", "JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Login Form (Thymeleaf)- embedded in navigation menu

```
<div th:fragment="login">
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="login-pane" id="login-form">
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sec-user">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="sec-user" name="sec-user" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sec-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="sec-password" name="sec-password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <button type="login-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And last but not least my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login-btn").click(login)

});

function login() {

    console.info("Attempting to authenticate");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/login',
        data: $('#login-form').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if (response.success == true) {
                console.info("Authentication Success!");
                window.location.href("/");
            }
            else {
                console.error("Unable to login");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error("Login failure");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling *login()* method that you have defined in javascript but actually posting to *login* action in the login form.

Remove the *post* action call and call your *login()* method on *onclick* event of Login button.

Comment: The issue was I had <button type="login-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button> instead of <button id="login-btw" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>